# How to read cookie's domain name from web.config?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

If I want to set up a multidomain authentication (or for whatever other reason I want to specify the authentication domain) I have to do it in two places:

1. In the web.config:

   ```
   <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" domain="mydomain.com" />
   ```
2. On the login page, when I am creating my authentication cookie:

   ```
   FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, user, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddHours(3), false, role, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
       string hash = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
       HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hash);
       cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;

       cookie.Domain = "mydomain.com"; // <-----
       Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
   ```

That is fine... but whenever I want to change the domain I have to do it in two places. Is there a way to read the domain straight from the < authentication >  tag in web.config? I know I could put it in the < appSettings > section and read it easily from wherever in the program, but then I would have to change it twice in the web.config file.

Comment: I have the same question. Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @MartinD.  Nope, sorry - I've decided to not use using multidomain cookies.

Answer (score 0):

you can set it in authentication/forms and read it as `FormAuthentication.CookieDomain`